# Can I slide polygons behind the text for cities?

Tags: here-api

I am using the Here.com JS API V 3. I have a situation where I need to put some large polygons over the map to show areas, but that also obscures the city names. Is there a way to force my group to go between or under a specific layer (specifically the text)?

Currently I am using a new H.map.Group() and then adding that to the map object. I have been through the layers documentation but do not see a way to identify the text and insert before that point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the attached example at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pczkLfwu/) which allows you to populated city names above the polygon.

The map is loaded with the default vector layer, after that the layer is split into two and the new object layer is inserted between them.

```
/**
 * The function add the "change" event listener to the map's style
 * and modifies colors of the map features within that listener.
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function interleave(map){
  var provider = map.getBaseLayer().getProvider();

  // get the style object for the base layer
  var style = provider.getStyle();

  var changeListener = () => {
    if (style.getState() === H.map.Style.State.READY) {
      style.removeEventListener('change', changeListener);

      // create a provider and a layer that are placed under the buildings layer
      objectProvider = new H.map.provider.LocalObjectProvider();
      objectLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(objectProvider);
      // add a circle to this provider the circle will appear under the buildings
      objectProvider.getRootGroup().addObject(new H.map.Circle(map.getCenter(), 5000));
      // add the layer to the map
      map.addLayer(objectLayer);

      // extract buildings from the base layer config 
      // in order to inspect the config calling style.getConfig()
      buildings = new H.map.Style(style.extractConfig(['roads.shields', 'road_labels', 'places.populated-places']));
      // create the new layer for the buildings
      buildingsLayer = platform.getOMVService().createLayer(buildings);
      // add the layer to the map
      map.addLayer(buildingsLayer);

      // the default object layer and its objects will remain on top of the buildings layer
      //map.addObject(new H.map.Marker(map.getCenter()));
    }
  }

  style.addEventListener('change', changeListener);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  center: {lat: 52.51477270923461, lng: 13.39846691425174},
  zoom: 10,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({tilt: 45});

// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Now use the map as required...
interleave(map);
```